# Firebase Chat node not updating properly In Release APK (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat App using Firebase. In debug mode, node gets updated properly and chat happens. But in Release mode node is updating as follows:

```
{
    a: "Hi",
    b: "-L4eVgsunE4iJMPtzYNP",
    c: 1517910415250,
    d: 0,
    e: "passenger"
}
```

where as it should be as follows:

```
{
    messageContent: "awef",
    messageId: "-L4GRcJTonRiq3S6ecC6",
    messageTimestamp: 1517489915463,
    messageType: 0,
    sender: "admin"
}
```

Comment: Did you check if you have to add any proguard rule? They tend to fail on release only

Comment: Yes I checked. Tried a few but still not working. Can you please help me with the actual proguard rules for this issue?

Comment: Did you alter your proguard rules in any way? Can you post them here?

Comment: Please add the proguard rules.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your model class is getting obfuscated. You can prevent it from the proguard rules by adding following:

```
-keep class com.your.path.to.model.** { *; }
```

for example if your model class is in package `com.example.model.Chat.java`

then it should be

```
-keep package com.example.model.** { *; }
```

Also, add the `@PropertyName` annotation in your model like

Chat.java [For example]

```
String messageContent;

@PropertyName("messageContent")
public String getMessageContent() {
   return messageContent;
}

@PropertyName("messageContent")
public void setMessageContent(String messageContent) {
   this.messageContent = messageContent
}
```